# Anti Forgery cookie missing in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Here is the scenario in my MVC 5 application:

I have a login form that includes @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
I have a controller that has the login post action decorated with ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Everything works as expected, except when I run the site in IE (v.11 in my case)

I ran the request through Fiddler and I noticed that the anti forgery cookie is not being sent when I used IE to log in.

Comment: Thanks, but you should add as answer and mark it as answered so people don't think its still an open question.

Comment: Good point.  Will update the question and add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was very strange indeed.  It took a lot of research, but I finally figured out the problem.  Apparently, IE does not accept cookies from URLs containing underscore.  In my case, this was a temp URL just for development and testing.

I am not sure what the reason for this behavior is, but after changing the URL, everything works as expected.

I thought I share my findings here.  Hopefully, this will save someone a few hours of their life :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after UI form validation my controller would fail to validate anti-forgery token, if the request was send by IE.

Example of the failed code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate();" />
```

my validate() function would return true/false based on validation conditions. So, if condition is true, the form had to be submitted. It worked everywhere except IE.

For some reason, a little delay before submitting the form after input validation fixes the problem.

I changed my button to

```
<button onclick="submit();">
 Submit
</button>
```

my submit() function:

```
var submit = function(){
  if($("#form").validate()){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#form").submit();
    }, 0);
  }
}
```